# How to draw a Gnatt Chart and calculate Arrival and Waiting times of scheduling algorithms if a priority queue is given?

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, round-robin

[image: Is Service Time the same as Burst time?]

Have to draw a Gnatt Chatt and calculate the Waiting time and Turnaround time of each of the following algorithm but with the priority queue it gets confusing.

1. Feedback (FB) q=3
2. Highest response ratio next
3. Round Robin q=4
4. Shortest remaining time
5. Shortest process next.

Help me out!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What confuses you about the priority queue? Do you remember how those 5 algorithms operate?

Comment: I know about the last 3 algorithms. I am confused about how to use priority queue in Round Robin and the others. I have tried Round Robin so far with a time quantum of 4 but I have no idea how to integrate priority queue in it. I have seen many youtube videos and in them the priority queue is given only in videos with the name "Priority CPU scheduling algorithm" and not with other algorithms.

Comment: And also let me know that is the last column Burst Time or something else.

Comment: Note that "shortest remaining time" only makes sense if you are allowed preemption, which is not stated in your problem. Are you allowed preemption?

Comment: Yes it is not stated in the problem which means that we can allow preemption.